# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null Chrome 2020

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This seems like a really simple problem but I just can't figure it out. In Chrome's Console log, I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null

This is my HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="deets">
        <h1>Document</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <canvas id="anim"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
// 1. test main.js is linked to index.html
console.log('it works!!');

// 2. test #document code is available
console.log(document);

// 3. test .getElementById("deets") and get .clientHeight
console.log(document.getElementById("deets").clientHeight);
```

The First and Second tests work, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the Third. Element id="deets" keeps returning as a null.

Would appreciate any help so much. Thanks!

Comment: Damn, I think I figured it out. Just had to move the <script> tag to the bottom of <body>. So easy! 

Comment: put your console calls in a window loaded event listener

Comment: even if you move the script at the bottom of the body, always access DOM elements after document loaded / window loaded. bcoz scripts loads faster than the DOM tree.

Comment: alos, accept @hrgui 's answer. its a SO standard to accept answers which are correct :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @user4642212 Very helpful, still getting used to search terminology so apologies if my question was similar to previous ones, I did try my best to look through previous threads! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try:

1. Consider moving `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` before the `</body>`?

This is because we're calling `document.getElementById("deets")` before the DOM elements are rendered.

2. If we need to call `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` in the head, consider using the [onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

Answer (score 0):

Put your js/main.js file in script tags at the end of your body section and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. You should move the script tag to bottom of body tag.

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="deets">
        <h1>Document</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <canvas id="anim"></canvas>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```